# Q: How can i add my own attribut while adding a post?

Tags: wordpress, field

I'm just asking a question : Is it possible to add our own `attribut/field` while i added a post ?

[image: Photo]

I don't want any code or anything else, just an answer to my question, i don't know what i have to type in Google to find my answers. I found some tutorials on "Custom Fields" but it didn't seems answer my question. I want to add in the yellow square, a simple option with a checkbox.
When this checkbox is checked, then `attribut statement` in `wp_posts` will be 1, if not 0.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way is to use Advanced Custom Fields.
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/
This is a popular plug and reliable. Also the documentation is awesome.

If you want to write code for this search custom meta box and custom fields. First check the official documentation.

Comment: I have download it this morning, i'm now on another issue. I want to display the value of custom field (which is a checkbox) in list posts. I write some functions in functions.php with filter and action 'manage_posts_columns'. Can we keep in touch about my advancement ?

Comment: To make an action hook is the best way but i dont now if you are ready yet. I think the best and easy way is to change the template. It demands less efford. The steps i recommend. 1. Read the documentation of checkbox https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/checkbox/ 2. find the template and display the value. If is a single value you will write onw line statement. If you have more tha one values loop with foreacj.

Comment: Thanks @PanSouk for your answer, i succeeded !